# Please look and advise

Tags: c

I am trying to learn how to write in C. I am new to the whole thing. Got stuck on code. Just trying to find out how to make this code in to a pop up box to ask a question and then do something with the answer.

I'll put the code in now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int age;
    printf ("whats yo age???"/*condition goes here */);
        scanf ("%d", age);
}

{    if (age <30)
        /*condition goes here */
        printf ("you a young buck");
        /*if condition is non-zero (true), this code will execute*/
}


{
   scanf
  if ( age==30);
    /*condition goes here*/
    printf ("you getting old");
    /*if condition is non-zero (true), this code will execute*/
}//
```

Comment: "id appreciate any help" --> `int age; ... scanf ("%d", age);` implies code is not compiled with warnings fully enabled.  Save time, lots of time and enable all warnings.  You get faster feedback than posting on SO.

Comment: You should start with [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the language fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

First of all you should put it in the main function block. (at least until you understand how functions work).
Then when you use `scanf`, most of the time you have to add `&` sign, which indicates you will place the value in variable which is located at this address. (variable `age` in your case)

The code should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int age;
    printf ("whats yo age???");
    scanf ("%d", &age);

    if (age < 30) {
        printf ("you a young buck");
    }
    else if (age == 30) {
      printf ("you getting old");
   }
}
```